# Link to handle $_GET request

Tags: database

I have a set of items retrieved from a database custom table that work. So believe me that `$ticket->ID` outputs some integer. Say I want to delete some of them. While printing them I offer a link to delete it. I'm begginer in Wordpress.

How can I handle that request? The problem is if I create manually a new page, i.e. delete-ticket.php for retrieving the `$_GET` data, I cannot access to Wordpress features.

```
echo '(<a href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/delete-ticket.php?ID='.$ticket->ID.'">Delete item</a>)</li>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in the admin, use the `action` parameter:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( "?action=delete_ticket&ticket_id=$ticket->ID" ) ?>">Delete item</a>
```

...and then hook appropriately:

```
function wpse_159391_delete_ticket() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['ticket_id'] ) ) {
        // delete it!
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_action_delete_ticket', 'wpse_159391_delete_ticket' );
```

For the front-end, you can just append your parameters to the current url and listen out for them on `template_redirect`:

```
function wpse_159391_delete_ticket() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['delete_ticket'] ) ) {
        $ticket_id = $_GET['delete_ticket'];
        // delete it!
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_159391_delete_ticket' );
```

To redirect after processing:

```
// Get the URL of the current page/post
if ( is_singular() )
    $url = get_permalink( get_queried_object_id() );

// Get custom URL
$url = home_url( 'my/url/path?arguments' );

// Get current URI with removed arguments
$url = remove_query_arg( 'delete_ticket' );

// Get current URI with added arguments
$url = add_query_arg( 'success', 'true' );

wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks! that helps a lot. Is there a reason to call your function 'wpse_159391_delete_ticket()'?

Comment: It's a de facto standard here on WPSE (see how it matches the question ID in the URL?) You can name it whatever you like.

Comment: I see now, yes. It is for front-end, so I would just use esc_url() right?

Comment: You can just use `<a href="?delete_ticket=..."`, no need for an absolute URL.

Comment: I can work with the data (i.e. the database query) inside the hook process. However, now, I don't know what to do in the template page to show the results. I mean, print the list without that ticket. I'll have to read.

Comment: If you don't need to make a redirect/process before header output, you could simply take the delete logic and place it right in the template (and forget about the `template_redirect` hook). It's a little dirty since we're processing data inside a template, but it's extremely easy to get working.

Comment: The problem is that I need that delete logic in many pages.

Comment: Last question. What is it the best way to redirect to another page from that function?

Comment: See my revised answer for handy snippets.

Comment: Is this the way to do this or is it a trick?

Comment: There is no *way* to do anything!